# Share specific desktop or space with OSX

Tags: macos, vnc, osx-spaces

How can I share a specific desktop or space so I can connect to it via VNC? I do a lot of local development and it would be nice to VNC into my laptop with my iPad and have all my local hostnames and applications running. I want to have my coding on one desktop and a web browser with live reload on another. VNC would work perfect if it would always show Desktop 2 instead of what is currently displaying on the laptop.

Answer (score -2):

Try [Screen Recycler](http://screenrecycler.com). It does exactly that...